# How can I pass a variable to Freeform's formatting template so that it's available to Twig?

Tags: templating, plugin-freeform

I want to be able to toggle the display of a form's Title on or off, without having to resort to using a mostly-identical copy of the formatting template.

Freeform formatting template:

```
{% if showFormTitle %}{{ form.name }}{% endif %}
```

How can I control the value of `showFormTitle` from the Twig template that renders the form? This (and all the permutations of it that I've tried) doesn't work:

```
{% set showFormTitle = true %}
{{ craft.freeform.form(myForm).render() }}
```

```
{% set showFormTitle = true %}
{{ craft.freeform.form(myForm).render() with { showFormTitle: showFormTitle } }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could potentially be handled a few different ways...

**1. Move the Form Title location**

Remove the Title from the formatting template and set up your main template loading the form to look something like this:

```
{% set form = craft.freeform.form('myForm')  %}

{% if showFormTitle %}
   {{ form.name }}
{% endif %}

{{ form.render }}
```

**2. Wait for Freeform 3.12**

Freeform 3.12 will be going into beta very soon and will have the ability to add something like this to the form payload:

```
{{ form.render({ showFormTitle: true }) }}
```

And in your formatting template, use:

```
{% if form.properties.showFormTitle %}
   {{ form.name }}
{% endif %}
```

**3. Use Conditional Rules feature**

You could use a combination of using the `overrideValues` parameter, Conditional Logic, and an HTML field with Twig parsing on.

1. Go to the form builder for this form.
2. Add an HTML field.
3. Add the value `{{ form.name }}` and any other formatting to the HTML block field.
4. Check off the **Allow Twig** checkbox.

   - If you don't see this option, be sure to upgrade to the latest version of Freeform and go to the *Form Builder Settings* area (Freeform -> Settings -> Form Builder Settings) and enable the **Allow Twig to be Enabled for each HTML block?** toggle.
5. Create a hidden field (for purpose of this example, let's give it a handle of `showTitleField`).
6. Go to the Conditional Rules tab in the form builder and add some logic for this. Something like: Show the HTML field only when `showTitleField` contains a value of `show`.
7. Save the form.
8. In your templates, where you call the form, add the `overrideValues` parameter and add a line for the hidden field. Something like:

   ```
   overrideValues: {
      showTitleField: "show"
   }
   ```

   - If you need to do something dynamic with that value, you can check out the guide here for [Passing Dynamic Data to Forms](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/guides/passing-dynamic-data-to-forms.html).

Comment: Wow. That's, uhh, quite a workaround! If I'm understanding it correctly, that's shifting the onus of rendering the form name from the formatting template itself, on to an HTML field _inside_ the form. While quite imaginatave, this isn't practical for the use-case I have as the title and the form fields are somewhat separated, HTML-wise. Also, it's a complex-enough solution that I might as well just clone the formatting template, minus the code for the form title. :-/ Might I submit the ability to pass Twig variables to formatting templates as a feature request? ;)

Comment: The other option you have would be rather simple... see next answer...

Comment: @Sandwich I have updated the answer to include some other options.

Comment: I see that! Option 1 is of course a very simple and sensible solution, however on a site that already has numerous forms scattered about on various pages, it's probably more work than it's worth. Option 2 sounds good, though! Might I suggest the ability to somehow override the form title, not just show or hide it? Perhaps `overrideValues: { name: "Custom Form Title" }`, or perhaps `{{ form.render({ formTitle: [true|false|"Custom Title"] }) }}` ?

Comment: Sure, I'll make a note about that for FR list - thanks! :)

Comment: I've got version 3.12.9.1. The code `{{ craft.freeform.form(entry.formField.handle,  formRenderSettings).render({ formTitle: 'hidden' }) }}` results in the error `Neither the property "properties" nor one of the methods "properties()", "getproperties()"/"isproperties()"/"hasproperties()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Form" in "__string_template__8dd7283256bc9c330b24d64d52715d2f1c033f64b05cb712c143bff47665e451" at line 19.`

Comment: Sorry @Sandwich, I can see it isn't working correctly either. We'll look into it and get a fix out tomorrow. :)

Comment: @Sandwich, this should now be fixed in Freeform 3.12.11. :)